# Pass the value by using href

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I use the following formatter option for add href button in last column of the jqgrid.Its working Fine.

```
       formatter: 
                 function (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
                 {
                  return "a href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")?obid='+rowObject[0]+'>View";
                 }
```

I need to pass the rowobject value to Action in controller.

I use the above method and I getting empty value in Action.How to pass the value to action?

Answer (score 4):

Use quotes properly

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "a href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")?obid=" + rowObject[0] + "'>View";
}
```